# Create Multiple Columns from a Single Column - Scala spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a data frame that has columns like this

```
| col_a    | col_b            |
| -------- | -----------------|
| First    | name=x, address=Y|
| Second   | name=x, address=Y|
```

I want to convert it in a data frame with col_b converted into two columns like this

```
| col_a    | name | address |
| -------- | -----|---------|
| First    | x    | Y       |
| Second   | x    | Y       |
```

is it possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: should be easy enough if you provide the code how the above dataframe is being generated. I suspect your col_b is a map which can be exploded to get the desired output but will need to see our code specially how you are generating the dataframe.

Comment: I am reading a tsv to generate the dataframe. The col is just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) since your column is interest is `StringType` and extract the relevant indexes using [getItem](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getItem.html) -

#### Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
First name=x,address=Y
Second name=x,address=Y
""".split()


input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str))

cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "col_a     col_b".split()))
            
n = len(input_values)
n_col = 2

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+n_col]) for i in range(0,n,n_col)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF.show()

+------+----------------+
| col_a|           col_b|
+------+----------------+
| First|name=x,address=Y|
|Second|name=x,address=Y|
+------+----------------+
```

#### Split

```
first_split_col = F.split(sparkDF['col_b'], ',')

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('name', F.split(first_split_col.getItem(0),'=').getItem(1))
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('address', F.split(first_split_col.getItem(1),'=').getItem(1))

sparkDF.show()

+------+----------------+----+-------+
| col_a|           col_b|name|address|
+------+----------------+----+-------+
| First|name=x,address=Y|   x|      Y|
|Second|name=x,address=Y|   x|      Y|
+------+----------------+----+-------+
```

Comment: Looks like a decent solution. accepting this. Just a small doubt what if name and address are in random order(first_column = `name=x, address=y` and second_column=`address=y, name=x`).

Comment: Since spark 2.4 you can use [array_sort](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#array_sort(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to sort your array on variable `first_split_column` and adapt `getItem` indexes accordingly when creating columns

Comment: You ll need to sort your respective column, before hand in case of random order